Drizzle ORM - Typesafe JSON Returns malformed array literal
when I have a type safe json array in my schema like this:
HistoricalData: json('History').$type<historyData[]>()
and I try to update like this:
const id = await db
                .update(myTable)
                .set({
                    Date: sql`now()`,
                    HistoricalData: history
                })
                .where(eq(myTable.myid, myid))
                .returning({ id: myTable.myid });

            return json(id);

I get the error: malformed array literal:
"[{"Date":"2024-08-29T08:40:52.325Z","Value1":"2419","Value2":"2393"}]"

It looks like drizzle can't correctly convert an object of type historyData, (which is stored in the variable history) to JSON during the database update.

...what's "malformed" about it? What is the exact error you are getting?

I got it working. It seems like drizzle converts arrays with only one object to an object. So it drops the []-brackets around it. That leads to it not accepting the input, because its not an array anymore. My solution is to initialize the array with two objects.
